# search for an element from a matrix using R

Tags: r, matrix

I try to use a function to select an element from a matrix. For example, I have a matrix M:

```
M <- matrix(1:100, nrow=20, ncol=50)
```

column names of M is seq(0.5,2,length=20), and row names of M is seq(-0.5,0.5,length=50). I can get any elements if input column and row names, such as M["0.5","0.3"]. The function used for searching for the element from M is:

```
search <- function(i,j) {M["i","j"]}.
```

This function doesn't work. Where is the mistake? Thanks!

Comment: I need to search for the elements according to column and row names.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes. You are effectively searching for columns "i" and "j", not the variables you input.

Comment: Lustrik Do you mean search<-function(i,j){M[i,j]}?

Comment: @smirk Sure, just try it. :)

Comment: @smirk The arguments have to be characters, i.e. `search("0.5", "0.2")`

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! I just figured out this problem. The correct way is search <- function(i,j) {M[as.character(i),as.character(j)]}.